# hadoop: how to show execution time of put command? Or How to show the duration of load a file in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How do I configure `put` command in hadoop so it shows the execution time?

Because this command:

```
hadoop fs -put table.txt /tables/table
```

is just returning this:

```
16/04/04 01:44:47 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: 
Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using    
builtin-java classes where applicable
```

The command works, but does not show any execution time. Do you know if it is possible the command shows the execution time? Or there is another way to get that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understating hadoop fs command does not provide any debug information like execution time, but you can get the execution time in two ways:

1. **The Bash way:** `start=$(date +'%s') && hadoop fs -put visit-sequences.csv /user/hadoop/temp && echo "It took $(($(date +'%s') - $start)) seconds"`
2. **From Log file:** You can check the namenode log file which lists all the details related to executed command, like how much time it took, file-size, replication etc.

e.g. I tried this command `hadoop fs -put visit-sequences.csv /user/hadoop/temp` and got below logs, specific to put operation, in log file.

```
2016-04-04 20:30:00,097 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Roll Edit Log from 127.0.0.1
2016-04-04 20:30:00,097 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Rolling edit logs
2016-04-04 20:30:00,097 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Ending log segment 38
2016-04-04 20:30:00,097 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 2 Total time for transactions(ms): 1 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 2 SyncTimes(ms): 75 
2016-04-04 20:30:00,118 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Number of transactions: 2 Total time for transactions(ms): 1 Number of transactions batched in Syncs: 0 Number of syncs: 3 SyncTimes(ms): 95 
2016-04-04 20:30:00,120 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FileJournalManager: Finalizing edits file /data/misc/hadoop/store/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_inprogress_0000000000000000038 -> /data/misc/hadoop/store/hdfs/namenode/current/edits_0000000000000000038-0000000000000000039
2016-04-04 20:30:00,120 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLog: Starting log segment at 40
2016-04-04 20:30:01,781 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.TransferFsImage: Transfer took 0.06s at 15.63 KB/s
2016-04-04 20:30:01,781 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.TransferFsImage: Downloaded file fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000039 size 1177 bytes.
2016-04-04 20:30:01,830 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 2 images with txid >= 0
2016-04-04 20:30:56,252 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: BLOCK* allocate blk_1073741829_1005{UCState=UNDER_CONSTRUCTION, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-1b928386-65b9-4438-a781-b154cdb9a579:NORMAL:127.0.0.1:50010|RBW]]} for /user/hadoop/temp/visit-sequences.csv._COPYING_
2016-04-04 20:30:56,532 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: BLOCK* blk_1073741829_1005{UCState=COMMITTED, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-1b928386-65b9-4438-a781-b154cdb9a579:NORMAL:127.0.0.1:50010|RBW]]} is not COMPLETE (ucState = COMMITTED, replication# = 0 <  minimum = 1) in file /user/hadoop/temp/visit-sequences.csv._COPYING_
2016-04-04 20:30:56,533 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileOutputStream: Nothing to flush
2016-04-04 20:30:56,548 INFO BlockStateChange: BLOCK* addStoredBlock: blockMap updated: 127.0.0.1:50010 is added to blk_1073741829_1005{UCState=COMMITTED, truncateBlock=null, primaryNodeIndex=-1, replicas=[ReplicaUC[[DISK]DS-1b928386-65b9-4438-a781-b154cdb9a579:NORMAL:127.0.0.1:50010|RBW]]} size 742875
2016-04-04 20:30:56,957 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.StateChange: DIR* completeFile: /user/hadoop/temp/visit-sequences.csv._COPYING_ is closed by DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_1242172231_1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do you check that log file? Im not finding it in the namenode url!

Comment: on master node, _[HADOOP_HOME]/logs/hadoop-[USERNAME]-namenode-[HOSTNAME].log_

Comment: Thanks! So the time is what appears in transfer took 0,06s right?

Comment: Log will not give us total time it took. We have to calculate, like [file transfer (replication) time + Edit log updation time ). I mean from start of edit file updation to "_COPYING_ is closed" statement.